# Given $f:\left(x,y\right) \mapsto \left(u,v\right)$, to find regions in $xy$-plane that map onto a given region in $uv$-plane

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by
$$\left(u,v\right)=f\left(x,y\right)=\left(x-y,xy\right)$$
**Problem :** Which regions in $xy$-plane map onto the rectangle $\left[0,1\right] \times \left[1,4\right]$ in the $uv$-plane.

**My progress :** $u=x-y,\,v=xy \Rightarrow y=\frac{-u\pm\sqrt{u^2+4v}}{2},\,x=\frac{2v}{-u\pm\sqrt{u^2+4v}}$. Thus, it is clear that there will be two regions in the $xy$-plane (one corresponding to $+\sqrt{u^2+4v}$ and the other corresponding to $-\sqrt{u^2+4v}$) that map to $\left[0,1\right] \times \left[1,4\right]$ in the $uv$-plane. The regions will be given by
\begin{align*}
&R_1=\left\{\left(\frac{2v}{-u+\sqrt{u^2+4v}},\frac{-u+\sqrt{u^2+4v}}{2}\right):\left(u,v\right) \in \left[0,1\right] \times \left[1,4\right]\right\}\\
&R_2=\left\{\left(\frac{2v}{-u-\sqrt{u^2+4v}},\frac{-u-\sqrt{u^2+4v}}{2}\right):\left(u,v\right) \in \left[0,1\right] \times \left[1,4\right]\right\}
\end{align*}

**Where I am stuck :** I cannot find $R_1$ and $R_2$ explicitly. Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming your calculations are correct, what do you mean by "explicitly"? I mean after all you now have a concrete parametrization of the sets you are looking for. If this is not the representation you may work with, maybe you could tell us how you intend to use the solution, so we may come up with a proper shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Here is a plot:

\begin{align}\color{blue}{0\leq x-y\leq1}\\
\color{green}{1\leq xy\leq4}\\
\end{align}
 [image]

A solution could thus be: $$(x,y)\in[1,2]\times \{1\}\cup\{2\}\times [1,2]$$
In general, any region that contains a curve which goes from one boundary of the blue region to the other, and the same for the green curve will do.

Comment: Thank you. About the diagram, did you use GeoGebra app?

Comment: Yes I did in fact use geogebra for the plot

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The segment from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$ that is $(x,y)=(t,1)$ with $t\in[0,1]$ is mapped to

$$(u,v)=(x-y,xy)=(t-1,t) \quad v=u+1$$

from $(-1,0)$ to $(0,1)$  and so on.